# How to create Zabbix Item and Trigger for 70% and more hosts ICMP ping losting in host group?

Tags: zabbix

Creating a trigger and item for a host group in a Zabbix monitoring system  to detect when 70% or more of the hosts in the group are unavailable via ICMP ping?

I tried but not worked this type of solving method

1. Define Your Host Group:
   First, ensure that all the hosts you want to monitor are added to a specific host group in Zabbix.
2. Set Up ICMP Pings:

   - Create an item for each host to ping them via ICMP.

     - Name: ICMP ping
     - Type: Simple check
     - Key: icmpping
     - Type of information: Numeric (unsigned)
     - Units: up
     - Use custom multiplier: No
     - Store value: As is
   - Once the item is created, it should return 1 for hosts that are up (reachable via ping) and 0 for hosts that are down (unreachable).
3. Aggregate Check:
   You'll need an aggregate check to determine the percentage of hosts that are down.

   - Create a new item:

     - Name: Percentage of hosts down
     - Type: Aggregate check
     - Key: grpsum["Your Host Group Name", "icmpping", "last", "0"] This checks the number of hosts that returned a value of 0 for the icmpping item in the specified group.
     - Type of information: Numeric (unsigned)
     - Units: %
4. Calculate the Percentage:
   You'll need to calculate the percentage of hosts that are down.

   - Create a new calculated item:

     - Name: Percentage of hosts down (calculated)
     - Type: Calculated
     - Key: percentage.hosts.down
     - Formula: (last("grpsum["Your Host Group Name", "icmpping", "last", "0"]")/total_number_of_hosts_in_group)*100
     - Type of information: Numeric (float)
     - Units: %
5. Create Trigger:
   Now, you can set up a trigger to notify you when the percentage of hosts that are down exceeds 70%.

   - Name: 70% of hosts in group are down
   - Expression: {Your Host:percentage.hosts.down.last()}>=70
   - Severity: Set it according to your preference (e.g., `High`)
6. Set Up Actions (Optional):
   If you want notifications or other actions to be executed when the trigger fires, set them up in the 'Actions' section of Zabbix.
7. Test Your Configuration:
   It's essential to test your configuration to ensure it's working correctly. Simulate a scenario where over 70% of your hosts are down and verify that the trigger fires and any associated actions take place.

Remember, the exact navigation and options might differ slightly based on the Zabbix version and any customization you might have. Always refer to the official Zabbix documentation or any relevant resources for the version you are using.